# Optimizing MATLAB work on N dim array(512,512,400)

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, optimization, matrix

I am working on images that are 512x512 pixels; I have written a code that analyzes my images and gives me the values that I need in matrices that have dimensions (512,512,400) in 10 minutes more or less, using pre-allocation.

My problem is when I want to work with this matrices: it takes me hours to see results and I want to implement some script that does what I want in much less time. Can you help me?

```
% meanm is a matrix (512,512,400) that contains the mean of every inputmatrix
% sigmam is a matrix (512,512,400) that contains the std of every inputmatrix 

% Basically what I want is that for every inputmatrix (512x512), that is stored inside
% an array of dimensions (512,512,400),
% if a value is higher than the meanm + sigmam it has to be changed with 
% the corrispondent value of meanm matrix.

p=400;
for h=1:p
    if (inputmatrix(:,:,h) > meanm(:,:,h) + sigmam(:,:,h))
       inputmatrix(:,:,h) = meanm(:,:,h);
    end
end
```

I know that MatLab performs better on matrices calculation but I have no idea how to translate this for loop on my 400 images in something easier for it.

Comment: `"mean of every inputmatrix"` doesn't make it sound very clear. If `meanm` is the mean across all 400 `inputmatrix` images, shouldn't it be of size `512 x 512` and not `51 x 512 x 400`?

Comment: I'm also confused about the size of `inputmatrix`. If it is (512x512) then how do you do `inputmatrix(:,:,h)` in your for loop? I'm guessing there is a typo here somewhere.

Comment: the meanm array of matrix has inside a mean matrix for each inputmatrix because I perform a particular mean: on every inputmatrix I do the mean of a point with its nearest neighbours. It is part of my analysis, and it gives me back the right result. the problem is working with this result.

Comment: @2cents I loop over all the inputmatrix I have, that is why the for loop to 400

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but try this - `inputmatrix(inputmatrix > meanm + sigmam) = meanm;`.

Comment: @Divakar I think you also need to use the logical indexing into meanm otherwise, the number of elements won't match up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the condition of your for loop to make a logical matrix

```
logical_mask = (meanm + sigmam) < inputmatrix;
inputmatrix(logical_mask) = meanm(logical_mask);
```

This should improve your performance by using two features of Matlab

1. [Vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)  uses matrix operations instead of loops. To quote the linked site "Vectorized code often runs much faster than the corresponding code containing loops."
2. [Logical Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) allows you to access all elements in your array that meet a condition simultaneously.

Comment: it gives me this error. 
`??? Error using ==> gt
Comparison operations on complex integers are obsolete.
Please compare REAL(X) and REAL(Y) instead.
 Error in ==> fun_defneu at
22
logical_mask = meanm + sigmam > matrix; `

Maybe the problem is that Matlab doesn't know, with logical operators, how to work on N-dimensional array...I don't know

Comment: Matlab can work with logical operators and n-dimensional arrays. It applies the operator element-wise. What your error is telling you is that at least one of your arrays contains complex numbers. I find this surprising because the mean and std of an image should not be complex, but if you think your values are correct, you can do one of two things. (1) Compare the real part of your complex numbers using `real` (2) Compare the magnitude of your complex numbers using `abs`.

Comment: I don't think it should be the problem, but also try adding parenthesis `logical_mask = (meanm + sigmam) < inputmatrix;`

Comment: I am really sure my values are correct since everything work if I just analyze one matrix a time. Anyway thank you, I have learned a lot from what you've write. I have decided to change point of view for this task and I will work on it in a different way. Thank you again. @2cents